# Docker mount namespace

Tags: docker

When i mount $docker run -v /tmp:/tmp -ti ubuntu /bin/bash  for the running container that uses the filesystem of the host . When i close the above container from exit command and i link the above container id with the new $docker run --volumes-from="closed container id" -ti ubuntu /bin/bash this as well uses 
/tmp files in the newly running container.how is this possible that even after closed the container it is still could be referred in other container.please explain me in a better way what is happening in docker.

Comment: can we able to mount new dev inside docker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is this possible that even after closed the container it is still could be referred in other container.please explain me in a better way what is happening in docker.

This is an expected behavior, because the you have mapped volume `-v /tmp:/tmp` on the first instance, which means you have mapped `/tmp` on your host OS to `/tmp` inside the container. Now any changes you make within the container remains on the host OS which is accessible by the second or third instance unless the `<container id>` is removed.

The container exists unless its removed with `docker rm <container id>`. You can get the `<container id>` from `docker ps -a`, which returns the list of all the containers which are running and have been exited AND not been removed.

Comment: when i remove the container what all the components/modules are got removed ?

Comment: Everything in the container gets removed, except for the shared volume shared with the host OS and the contents of the file or dir.

Comment: i observed a difference is that,when i give the $docker run -v /tmp:/tmp -ti ubuntu /bin/bash  container ID with other newly running container. then i delete the referred container, but i could able to see the mount point point inside the referencing container.Is there any reference count is maintained inside the kernel mount code? How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Check Container Solution's [Understanding Volumes in Docker](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/)

Comment: How the read-only layer of docker is added with read-write layer when we use that image to mount for dockers?Can i get the code snippet that makes read-write layer on docker image?